# Cross Compiling Openssl for MIPS

Tags: compiling, gcc, openssl, mips

I've been trying to cross compile Ncat for the MIPS architecture (big endian), and I really need SSL support, so I first must compile OpenSSL. I downloaded the latest version from Github and configured like this because my toolchain binaries are named like 'mips-gcc mips-ld...etc :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/toolchain
./Configure linux-mips32 --cross-compile-prefix=mips-
```

That configured the makefile using the cross toolchain, like:

```
CC=mips-gcc 
LD=mips-ld 
AR=mips-ar 
RANLIB=mips-ranlib
```

So, I ran `make`

I got these errors the first run:

```
../libcrypto.a(async_posix.o): In function `async_global_init':
async_posix.c:(.text+0x278): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
async_posix.c:(.text+0x2a4): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/anon/Source/openssl/apps'
make[1]: *** [openssl] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/anon/Source/openssl/apps'
make: *** [build_apps] Error 1
```

I read on another thread to add the option `-lpthread` to my CFLAGS, but I am still getting the same error. Someone else suggested using G++ instead off GCC (does that even make sense?). Now I get this error instead:

```
s_socket.o: In function `do_server':
s_socket.c:(.text+0x6d4): warning: gethostbyaddr is obsolescent, usegetaddrinfo() instead.
s_socket.o: In function `host_ip':
s_socket.c:(.text+0x100): warning: gethostbyname is obsolescent, use getnameinfo() instead.
../libcrypto.a(async.o): In function `async_fibre_swapcontext':
async.c:(.text+0x248): undefined reference to `setcontext'
../libcrypto.a(async_posix.o): In function `async_fibre_makecontext':
async_posix.c:(.text+0x154): undefined reference to `getcontext'
async_posix.c:(.text+0x1b4): undefined reference to `makecontext'
make[2]: *** [link_app.] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/anon/Source/openssl/apps'
make[1]: *** [openssl] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/anon/Source/openssl/apps'
make: *** [build_apps] Error 1
```

The cflags I am using are:

```
CFLAG= -DOPENSSL_THREADS -pthread -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -mips2 -mabi=32 -Wall -DBN_DIV3W -O3 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DAES_ASM -lpthread
```

OPTIONS look like:

```
--cross-compile-prefix=mips- no-deprecated no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 no-jpake no-md2 no-rc5 no-sctp no-shared no-ssl-trace no-store no-unit-test no-zlib no-zlib-dynamic static-engine
```

I've search all over the net looking for a solution. I am not very experienced with compiling C, and at this point I am stuck. I'd really appreciate some help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you to replace OpenSSL with LibreSSL because LibreSSL has much more generic configure system instead of OpenSSL mess. It's more suitable for cross compiling. In the rest, they're _nearly_ same, LibreSSL omits some vulnerable features though.

Comment: Can I used them interchangably? I mean, could I compile nmap/ncat and tell it to use libressl as the ssl path?

Comment: LibreSSL _should_ serve as a drop-in replacement, but certain vulnerable things are missing from it (for example, SSLv3). I do not yet know what Nmap requires. Try it.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will report back once I give this a shot.

Comment: Okay, well compiling with mbedtls seemed to work-- but now... 
Compiling libpcap
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/anon/Source/nmap-7.01/libpcap'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `pcap-no.o', needed by `libpcap.a'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/anon/Source/nmap-7.01/libpcap'
make: *** [build-pcap] Error 2 ... where do I get libpcap? It compiles fine for my host systems (ubuntu trusty x64), but not for mips..

Comment: This shows that nmap's included libpcap is broken somewhere in it's build system, or you had installed few dependencies. You can get libpcap source from tcpdump.org.

Comment: Must be broken, because I have tcpdump. Unless there's some dev package I need?

Comment: You need libpcap.a for mips being available during linking.

Comment: I ended up getting this work with mbedtls eventually. Buildroot is making it easier all of the time as well.You were right about needing the lib.a , that did the trick.